# Register view_helper zf 1.10.3

Tags: zend-framework, view, helper

I create my view helper it located in /library/My/View/helpers/SpecialPurpose.php
the class name is My_View_Helper_SpecialPurpose it have public function specialPurpose() it return some HTML

i register this path in bootstrap.php

$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
$view->addBasePath('/my/view/helpers',"My_View_Helper");

when i tring specialPurpose();?> in any view .phtml

it trow exeption

```
Message: Plugin by name 'SpecialPurpose' was not found in the registry; used paths: My_View_Helper_Helper_: /my/view/helpers\helpers/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/;D:/WWW/zends/application/modules/default/views\helpers/
```

P.S I read many post in stackoverflow but not one solutions not helped
If it possible weácan how do this task with bootstrap and application.ini
zf version 1.10.3

Answer (score 1):

Rename:

`My/View/helpers/SpecialPurpose.php`

to:

`My/View/Helper/SpecialPurpose.php`

that is, change the name of the `helpers` folder.
When adding the view helper path add it like:

`$view->addHelperPath('My/View/Helper', 'My_View_Helper');`

Answer (score 0):

you can register view helper in application.ini too

```
resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper=APPLICATION_PATH "My/Views/Helpers"
```

if your path is  APPLICATION_PATH "My/Views/Helpers"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . 'My/View/Helper', 'My_View_Helper');`

(Have you called Zend_Layout::startMvc(); in your Bootstrap?) The best "Zend way" to do this is in Bootstrap::_initView()

Your helper should be in `APPLICATION_PATH/My/View/Helper` and the name should be `class My_View_Helper_SpecialPurpose extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract`

EDIT: Path should be `APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/My/View/Helper`

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, for me, it was because i had

"resources.view[] ="

Inside of my application.ini. I needed to get rid of it. 
The Zend Quickstart tutorial has this in its config, but is an error from what i can tell.
An error in your application.ini may be cascading the error

Answer (score 0):

Call the class Zend_View_Helper_SpecialPurpose instead. It'll work.